# how to Iterate value sequentially in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How to Iterate value sequentially in selenium-IDE
    type    id=name22    441
    type    id=name32    442
    type    id=name42    443
    type    id=name52    444
    type    id=name62    445
    type    id=name72    446
    type    id=name82    447
    type    id=name92    448
    type    id=name102   449
    How can i  iterate value sequentially  in selenium-IDE.Here i want to iterate the value sequentially.how can i achieve it?

```
When i try this code but it is not working
store   440 i
store   javascript {storedVars.i++;}    
echo    ${i}    
type    id=name22   ${i}
type    id=name32   ${(i)+}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try following code:

```
store    440    i
store    0      looptimes
store    22     customVariable
while    storedVars.looptimes<==8
store    javascript{storedVars.i++}
storeEval    storedVars['i']=${i}
type    id=name${customVariable}     ${i}
store     ${customVariable}+10    customVariable
storeEval    storedVars['customVariable']=${customVariable}
store    javascript{storedVars.looptimes++;}
endWhile
```

I wrote this from my head, so please comment my answer if you need a clarification